# SAP Ui5 error-> Failed to load formatter file while executing programme

Tags: sapui5

I am newbie to ui5 technology and was trying to implement formatters but while debugging getting console error that formatter file is unable to upload. I have checked documentation part in ui5.sap.com. but couldn't find the error.

view page of program

[image]

controller page of program

[image]

formatter page of program

[image]

Data model page of program

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, and definitely do not post them as links inside code blocks that are not even actual links. You know you can just copy the text here and format with the code tool?

Comment: Okay James will be careful from now on.Thanks

Comment: In your case a formatter is not even necessary: `text="{fName} {lName}"`

Comment: yes Marc, but i was just practicing formatter :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks quite OK. There still could be a problem with your path to the formatter.js.
Is your `formatter.js` really in `/webapp/Util`? (beware, its case-sensitive!)

Maybe you can try to leave out the namespace and use relative paths

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
    "../Util/formatter"
], function (Controller, JSONModel, formatter) {
```

Comment: I tried relative paths but error is same. path of file is same as shown in image above revisionFormatter/revisionFormatter/Util/formatter

Comment: What's exactly the error you are getting in the console?

Comment: exact error code while cosole debugging is -> "failed to load JavaScript resource: revisionFormatter/revisionFormatter/Util/formatter.js -  sap.ui.ModuleSystem"

Comment: This really sounds like a typo in the path of `revisionFormatter/revisionFormatter/Util/formatter.js` 
Just to be sure, put the formatter.js in the controller directory and define it as `"./formatter"`